# combining two array of objects together in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

Hello i have two arrays of objects that look like this, but it's much more bigger, the second array contains the normal history and average value per day of the same history, i want to combine the NewHistory inside the first array ( input1 ) or into combine both of them into one array of objects

```
const input1= const input = [{
  name: 'xy',
  lastname: 'yx',
  history: [
  { "value": 0.02, "date": "2022-08-02T23:03:22.895Z" }, 
  { "value": 0.04, "date": "2022-08-02T22:03:16.603Z" },
  { "value": 0.08, "date": "2022-08-02T21:03:20.378Z" },
  { "value": 0.02, "date": "2022-08-01T23:03:32.584Z" },
  { "value": 0.04, "date": "2022-08-01T22:03:30.311Z" }]
},
{
  name: 'op',
  lastname: 'po',
  history: [
  { "value": 0.02, "date": "2022-08-02T23:03:22.895Z" }, 
  { "value": 0.04, "date": "2022-08-02T22:03:16.603Z" },
  { "value": 0.08, "date": "2022-08-02T21:03:20.378Z" },
  { "value": 0.02, "date": "2022-08-01T23:03:32.584Z" },
  { "value": 0.04, "date": "2022-08-01T22:03:30.311Z" }]
}
]

const input2 = [{
      history: [
      { "value": 0.02, "date": "2022-08-02T23:03:22.895Z" }, 
      { "value": 0.04, "date": "2022-08-02T22:03:16.603Z" },
      { "value": 0.08, "date": "2022-08-02T21:03:20.378Z" },
      { "value": 0.02, "date": "2022-08-01T23:03:32.584Z" },
      { "value": 0.04, "date": "2022-08-01T22:03:30.311Z" }]
      NewHistory: [
      { "value": 0.04, "date": "2022-08-02" }, 
      { "value": 0.03, "date": "2022-08-01" }]
    },
    {
      history: [
      { "value": 0.02, "date": "2022-08-02T23:03:22.895Z" }, 
      { "value": 0.04, "date": "2022-08-02T22:03:16.603Z" },
      { "value": 0.08, "date": "2022-08-02T21:03:20.378Z" },
      { "value": 0.02, "date": "2022-08-01T23:03:32.584Z" },
      { "value": 0.04, "date": "2022-08-01T22:03:30.311Z" }],
      NewHistory: [
      { "value": 0.04, "date": "2022-08-02" }, 
      { "value": 0.03, "date": "2022-08-01" }]
    }
    ]
```

i want to combine these two arrays of objects together to get this result

```
const input3 = [{
      name: 'xy',
      lastname: 'yx',
      history: [
      { "value": 0.02, "date": "2022-08-02T23:03:22.895Z" }, 
      { "value": 0.04, "date": "2022-08-02T22:03:16.603Z" },
      { "value": 0.08, "date": "2022-08-02T21:03:20.378Z" },
      { "value": 0.02, "date": "2022-08-01T23:03:32.584Z" },
      { "value": 0.04, "date": "2022-08-01T22:03:30.311Z" }],
      NewHistory: [
      { "value": 0.04, "date": "2022-08-02" }, 
      { "value": 0.03, "date": "2022-08-01" }]
    },
    {
      name: 'op',
      lastname: 'po',
      history: [
      { "value": 0.02, "date": "2022-08-02T23:03:22.895Z" }, 
      { "value": 0.04, "date": "2022-08-02T22:03:16.603Z" },
      { "value": 0.08, "date": "2022-08-02T21:03:20.378Z" },
      { "value": 0.02, "date": "2022-08-01T23:03:32.584Z" },
      { "value": 0.04, "date": "2022-08-01T22:03:30.311Z" }]
      NewHistory: [
      { "value": 0.04, "date": "2022-08-02" }, 
      { "value": 0.03, "date": "2022-08-01" }]
    }
    ]
```

until now i tried to do a map through both the array but i can't seem to make it work, any input on this ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can the same value exist in both arrays? Are there any duplicates? If so how should they be handled? How should they be overwritten? Only the second array has `NewHistory`? Do you want to basically add the `NewHistory` from the second array to the first one? You can search in libraries like `ramda`. Maybe [https://ramdajs.com/docs/#mergeDeepLeft](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#mergeAll) can help you.

Comment: Check my answer I added what I think is a working solution, please give feedback if not.

Comment: Hello @c0m1t , Yes i just need to add the newHistory from the first array to the object in the second array, the first one from from input2 will go in the first one in input1 and we go on, is there maybe a way to do it with now extra libraries ?

Comment: BTW I had to fix the first assignment because you have 2 const, why is this?

Comment: Check my second edit, I think it's as you want.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution can simply be something like:

`input1.forEach((element, i) =>  {element.NewHistory = input2[i].NewHistory});`

Comment: It's working fine now, thank you for your input ! this will help me a lot !

Answer (score 0):

you can use destructuring like bellow. simple ha!

```
const input3 = [...input1, ...input2];
```